# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'?

Tags: python, csv

everybody.
I am currently working to merge the csv files.
For example, you have files from filename1 to filename100.
I used the following code to combine 100 files and the following error occurred:
I'll put the code up first.
    import csv

```
fout=open("aossut.csv","a")
# first file:
for line in open("filename1.csv"):
    fout.write(line)
# now the rest:    
for num in range(2,101):
    f = open("filename"+str(num)+".csv")
    f.next() # skip the header
    for line in f:
         fout.write(line)
    f.close() # not really needed
fout.close()
```

And the following error occurred when the above file was executed:

```
File "C:/Users/Jangsu/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/tal.py", line 10, in 
<module>
    f.next() # skip the header
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'
```

I've been working on it for a few days, and I don't know what to do.

Comment: `f.next` would work in Python 2; in Python 3 `next` is spelled `__next__`. The built-in function `next` will work on both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file object doesn't have `next` method. Instead use `next(f)` to skip the first line

```
for num in range(2,101):
    with open("filename"+str(num)+".csv") as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            fout.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you.
But there's a lot of questions that I'm curious about. 
When you merge the csv files, you try to combine the values in the row columns in the corresponding file, and the row values are combined. How can I add the value of a column?

Answer (score 0):

The method "next()" in csv library is updated to **next**() in python 3. you can see the details in this link : https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html